# Any Over the Air xml samples for android devices?

Tags: android, xml, ota

I have searched a looot and could not find any website that shows ota xml samples for android devices. I'd like to know if anyone can post a sample xml or a useful link for android gingerbread and android ics?
thanks

DETAILS: Many devices get configured over-the-air (hence the name ota) remotely by sending an XML file as a binary message. The configuration can be for gprs apn, mms apn, emails, etc... 
an example of XML files is

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
<characteristic type="BOOTSTRAP">
<parm name="NAME" value="YandexMobile"/>
</characteristic>
<characteristic type="NAPDEF">
 <parm name="NAME" value="YandexMobile"/>
  <parm name="NAPID" value="YandexMobile_NAPID"/>
  <parm name="BEARER" value="GSM-GPRS"/>
  <parm name="NAP-ADDRESS" value="m.yandex.ru"/>
  <parm name="NAP-ADDRTYPE" value="APN"/>
  <parm name="INTERNET"/>
 <characteristic type="NAPAUTHINFO">
 <parm name="AUTHTYPE" value="PAP"/>
 <parm name="AUTHNAME" value="test"/>
  <parm name="AUTHSECRET" value="test"/>  
  < /characteristic> 
 </characteristic>
 </wap-provisioningdoc>
```

are there such samples for android devices?

Comment: Over the air XML? Could you explain what you mean in a little more depth please

Comment: @Blundell please check the edited question with details

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Kannel 1.5.0 User Guide, "Using the HTTP interface to send OTA configuration messages" which has all of the information you need to get started. You can begin by setting up the system using a mobile dongle, and if you need to send larger campaigns have a look at purchasing an SMPP interface so that the ESME may submit more directly to the network.

http://www.kannel.org/download/1.5.0/userguide-1.5.0/userguide.html#AEN4838